# How to identify similar dataset, and differences from both csv files to new df in R

Tags: r, join, multiple-columns

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("632592651","633322173","634703802","634927873","635812953","636004739","636101211","636157799","636263106","636752420"),text=c("asdf","cat","dog","mouse","elephant","goose","rat","mice","kitty","kitten"),response=c("y","y","y","n","n","y","y","n","n","y"))
```

overview of df1

```
        id     text response
1  632592651     asdf        y
2  633322173      cat        y
3  634703802      dog        y
4  634927873    mouse        n
5  635812953 elephant        n
6  636004739    goose        y
7  636101211      rat        y
8  636157799     mice        n
9  636263106    kitty        n
10 636752420   kitten        y


df2 <- data.frame(id=c("632592651","633322173","634703802","634927873","635812953","636004739","636101211","636157799","636263106","636752420","636809222","2004722036","2004894388","2005045755","2005535472","2005630542","2005788781","2005809679","2005838317","2005866692"),
                  text=c("asdf_xyz","cat","dog","mouse","elephant","goose","rat","mice","kitty","kitten","tiger_xyz","lion","leopard","ostrich","kangaroo","platypus","fish","reptile","mammals","amphibians_xyz"),
                  volume=c("1234","432","324","333","2223","412346","7456","3456","2345","2345","6","345","23","2","4778","234","8675","3459","8","9"))
```

overview of df2

```
  id           text volume
1   632592651       asdf_xyz   1234
2   633322173            cat    432
3   634703802            dog    324
4   634927873          mouse    333
5   635812953       elephant   2223
6   636004739          goose 412346
7   636101211            rat   7456
8   636157799           mice   3456
9   636263106          kitty   2345
10  636752420         kitten   2345
11  636809222      tiger_xyz      6
12 2004722036           lion    345
13 2004894388        leopard     23
14 2005045755        ostrich      2
15 2005535472       kangaroo   4778
16 2005630542       platypus    234
17 2005788781           fish   8675
18 2005809679        reptile   3459
19 2005838317        mammals      8
20 2005866692 amphibians_xyz      9
```

Above are my two dataframes and I would like to have a new df3 that gives

```
df3 <- data.frame(id=c("633322173","634703802","634927873","635812953","636004739","636101211","636157799","636263106","636752420"),
                  text=c("cat","dog","mouse","elephant","goose","rat","mice","kitty","kitten"),
                  response=c("y","y","n","n","y","y","n","n","y"),
                  volume=c("432","324","333","2223","412346","7456","3456","2345","2345"))
```

overview of df3

```
         id     text response volume
1 633322173      cat        y    432
2 634703802      dog        y    324
3 634927873    mouse        n    333
4 635812953 elephant        n   2223
5 636004739    goose        y 412346
6 636101211      rat        y   7456
7 636157799     mice        n   3456
8 636263106    kitty        n   2345
9 636752420   kitten        y   2345
```

and would like to obtain the differences between df1 and df2. Can someone give an advise how to approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `inner_join` and `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = c("id", "text")) 

         id     text response volume
1 633322173      cat        y    432
2 634703802      dog        y    324
3 634927873    mouse        n    333
4 635812953 elephant        n   2223
5 636004739    goose        y 412346
6 636101211      rat        y   7456
7 636157799     mice        n   3456
8 636263106    kitty        n   2345
9 636752420   kitten        y   2345
```

And

```
df1 %>%
  anti_join(df2, by = c("id", "text"))

         id text response
1 632592651 asdf        y

df2 %>%
  anti_join(df1, by = c("id", "text"))
           id           text volume
1   632592651        asdfxyz   1234
2   636809222      tiger_xyz      6
3  2004722036           lion    345
4  2004894388        leopard     23
5  2005045755        ostrich      2
6  2005535472       kangaroo   4778
7  2005630542       platypus    234
8  2005788781           fish   8675
9  2005809679        reptile   3459
10 2005838317        mammals      8
11 2005866692 amphibians_xyz      9
```

Comment: I believe op is looking for `inner_join` nice solution ..

Comment: Can't believe the solution is this easy. Thank you so much!